# Передача данных между вкладками и при переходах между страницами

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Есть задача, создать в пределах сайта чат, в окно которого будут поступать уведомления о новых сообщениях. Нужно, чтобы данные в этом чате сохранялись при переходе пользователя с одной страницы на другую в пределах сайта + при нескольких открытых вкладках данные там тоже были актуальными. По передаче данных между вкладками можно использовать LocalStorage, на SO нашел подобные вопросы, а как реализовать такое при переходах по страницам?

Comment: а вы пытались? есть хоть зачатки кода?

Comment: Получение данных с сервера и их обновление уже готовы.
Реализации передачи данных естесственно нет, так как возник вопрос на основе чего делать
Между вкладками как передать данные я понимаю, вопрос с обновлением страницы и переходом между ними.

Comment: @Максим Медведев   пользуйтесь nodejs + socket.io https://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/
Сообщения пишите в базу ,а когда переходите по страницам срабатывает событие connect,при нем можно извлечь из базы и показать

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. localstorage хранит данные не для текущей страницы, а для текущего домена и если Вы прейдёте на другую страницу своего сайта у Вас все данные сохранятся.

1. При инициализации страницы Вам нужно считать данные из хранилища
2. Подписаться на сервер на новые сообщения.
3. Подписываетесь на событие `onstorage`. И при добавлении в хранилище новых данных добавляете сообщение.
4. После добавления сообщения проверяете есть ли оно в хранилище если есть, то не добавляете, а если нет то добавляете.
5. Можно использовать SharedWorker для снижения нагрузки на сервер для того что бы всем вкладкам одновременно приходило сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы при переходе с одной страницы на другую в пределах сайта корректно поступали уведомления о новых сообщениях нужно реализовать данный функционал на каждой странице сайта. А для синхронизации вкладок можно использовать событие onstorage, как вы верно подметили.